# How to compute Bloomberg T-Bill yield in BXT?

Tags: fixed-income, bond, bloomberg, treasuries, treasury

could any kind soul explain how are the Discount and Yield computed? Also, do they refer to “Discount Yield (daycount Act/360)” and “Yield (daycount Act/365)” respectively? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: The Discount rate is based on ACt360, the coupon equivalent yield is based on replicating a treasury bond paying a 0% coupon, i.e. the yield is  calculated under an "ActActICMA" convention with semi-annual frequency. The formulae can be traced via the posted link to Treasury website.

Comment: Note that there are 349 days between 08/25/2023 and 08/08/2024 and `=(100-96.103000)*(360/349)` gives 4.019828

Comment: Next the yield. `=100/96.103000` gives 1.040550243. The equation for semiannual compounding with two periods (a full period and a partial period)  is `1.040550243 = (1+y/2)*(1+(y/2)*((349-183)/183))` we have to solve iteratively for y. I will skip you the details and just verify that 4.210387%  satisfies this: `=(1+0.04210387/2)*(1+(0.04210387/2)*((349-183)/183))` gives 1.04055024 as desired.